# Best practice to get EntityManger and UserTransaction from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jboss7.x, entitymanager

I am currently trying to figure out the best way to get a entity manager and a usertransaction in my application.

In JBoss 5.1 I was able to inject it directly into the JSP file, but this is not permitted anymore:

```
<%!@PersistenceContext(unitName = "unitname")
    public EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;
%>
```

I have to access `em` and `utx` from different locations in my application such as Servlets and Controller classes. So it would be great to have it in one place and to access it globally, but I did not figure out yet how to do it. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: IIRC, you are not supposed to inject entitymanagers into servlets/JSP because you cannot be sure that they are not being used in another thread (and entitymanages are not thread safe).

Comment: Yep, but what is the best way to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how to get the EntityManager and the UserTransaction in Servlets, Controller Classes and JSP files.

Let's start with SessionBeans. I redefined all my controller classes as Stateless SessionBeans. Session Beans allow ressource injection. This is how I did it:

```
@Stateless
public class UserHandling {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "SSIS2")
  private static EntityManager em;

  @Resource
  private UserTransaction utx;

  public User getUser(int userId) {
    User userObject = em.find(User.class, userId);
    return userObject;
  }
}
```

If another Session Bean is needed in a Session Bean Class, it can be injected with the `@EJB` annotation:

```
@Stateless
public class UserHandling {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "SSIS2")
  private static EntityManager em;

  @Resource
  private UserTransaction utx;

  @EJB
  UserHandling uh; RoleHandling rh; 

  public User getUser(int userId) {
    User userObject = em.find(User.class, userId);
    return userObject;
  }
}
```

In JSP files, you can get the Session Bean Controller classes by lookup the InitialContext:

```
<%
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    UserHandling uh = (UserHandling) ic.lookup("java:app/" + application.getContextPath() + "/UserHandling");
%>
```

Answer (score 4):

### The Issue being Solved

Servlets and JSPs must be stateless because they are shared across multiple threads.  An `EntityManager` does keep state, and so a single instance cannot be shared by concurrent threads.

We'd like a smooth/seamless mechanism for obtaining an EntityManager, preferably managed by the Servlet container.

### Servlet-Container Managed Persistence Context

Let's introduce a `ContainerManagedPersistenceContext` into the Servlet/JSP runtime.

We'll define it in a moment.  Let's first look at how it can be used to inject an `EntityManager` into `JSP`:

```
<%! @Inject
    @ContainerManagedPersistenceContext.Qualifier
    public EntityManager em;
%>
```

or, better yet into a controller (because we do want to separate data recovery/business logic from our JSP, right?):

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionController implements Serializable
{
    ...

    @Inject
    @ContainerManagedPersistenceContext.Qualifier
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

#### But I don't (yet) have CDI available

If you don't have CDI, but you do have JSF, then the context can be injected as an old-style standard JSF `@ManagedProperty`:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionController implements Serializable
{
    ...

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{containerManagedPersistenceContext}")
    ContainerManagedPersistenceContext cmpContext;

    ...
    public void myMethod() {
        EntityManager em = cmpContext.getEntityManager();
       try {
            ...
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that - for all the same reasons that we have to go to this effort in the first place - the `EntityManager` must never be cached/preserved anywhere.

#### Transactions

Use the `EntityTransaction` provided by the `EntityManager` for begin/commit/rollback:

> EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

### ContainerManagedPersistenceContext

This is defined as an application scoped controller and a `PersistenceContext`:

```
@PersistenceContext(name = ContainerManagedPersistenceContext.NAME,
                    unitName = ContainerManagedPersistenceContext.UNIT_NAME)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ContainerManagedPersistenceContext implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // UNITNAME must match persistence.xml: <persistence-unit name="myUnitName">
    public static final String UNITNAME = "myUnitName";
    public static final String NAME = "persistence/" + UNIT_NAME;


    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD,
             ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
    public static @interface Qualifier { }

    // Servlets must be stateless (shared across multiple threads).
    // EntityManager is not stateless (cannot be shared across threads).
    // Obtain Container Managed EntityManager - and do NOT cache.
    @Produces @Qualifier
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() throws NamingException
    {
        EntityManager lookup = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/" + NAME);
        return lookup;
    }
}
```

#### Limitations

As written, this defines a specifically named PersistenceContext for the Servlet container.  Since the `unitName` isn't parameterized, it doesn't provide the level of flexibility as:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "unitname")
public EntityManager em;
```

#### Alternatives

[Define a PersistenceContext on your Servlet, and use JNDI name lookup](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-get-container-managed.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well i think you should see the problem from a different point of view?
Why do you need to call an `EJB` from `JSP` page?

`JSP` page shouldn't contain codes and it is used only for presentation.
I suggest to you to add a `Servlet` or a `JSF framework` and let the `Servlet` or the `ManagedBean` to call `EJB` and then pass the parameters to the `JSP`.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following snippet to retrieve EntityManager and/or UserTransaction via JNDI lookup:

```
try {
   Context ic = (Context) new InitialContext();
   EntityManager em = (EntityManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/*<persistence-context-name>*");
   UserTransaction ut = (UserTransaction) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/UserTransaction");
} catch (NamingException ne) {...}
```

Comment: Could you shortly explain the Strings `java:comp/env/persistence/name` and `java:comp/env/UserTransaction`?

Comment: JNDI naming/lookup is quite broad and sometimes puzzling topic. You should look first at [JEE 6 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr316/index.html) chapter #EE.5

Comment: This did not work for me. I can get the `EntityManagerFactory` but if I create the `EntityManager`, it is `null`.